# NoSuchElementException while joining whatsapp group using selenium and python3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to automate WhatsApp group joining using selenium and python. I can almost reach the final page but can't find the Join group button. This is my python code. Please note that first I'm logging in to WhatsApp using a 5 seconds wait time.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
  
# create webdriver object
driver = webdriver.safari.webdriver.WebDriver(quiet=False)

driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
import time 
time.sleep(5)


driver.get("https://chat.whatsapp.com/invite/ANY_WA_GROUP_LINK")

# create action chain object
action = ActionChains(driver)

element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Join Chat")
action.click(on_element = element)
action.perform()

element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("use WhatsApp Web")
action.click(on_element = element)
action.perform()

element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Join group")
action.click(on_element = element)
action.perform()
```

Following is the error that I am getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basic.py", line 25, in <module>
    element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Join group")
  File "/Users/Home/WorkSpace/anaconda3/envs/env_auto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 428, in find_element_by_link_text
    return self.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
  File "/Users/Home/WorkSpace/anaconda3/envs/env_auto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/Users/Home/WorkSpace/anaconda3/envs/env_auto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/Home/WorkSpace/anaconda3/envs/env_auto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message:
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your locator is correct you are missing the wait / delay before `element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Join Chat")`.
So, just try adding

```
time.sleep(5)
```

before

```
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Join Chat")
```

UPD:
Try this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(),'Join group')]')
```

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. There is some webpage issue. The page get changed and the source remains the older one or something like that.

Comment: OK, after the page change and whatever, once it finally get stable, are there element matched by `link_text("Join Chat")` there? Maybe you simply using a wrong locator

Comment: It was a issue of locator. But can't navigate and click on the button

Comment: `<div role="button" tabindex="0" class="_1dwBj _3xWLK"><div class="_3NCXc _1Yw2u _FUG3 _2HGw4"><div class="VtaVl -TvKO">Join group</div></div></div>`

Comment: How do I click the div with role button

Comment: Like a regular `div` element. Try this XPath: '//div[contains(text(),'Join group')]'. I'm updating the answer

Comment: not working. Do I need a action.perform(). If I remove that the error is gone, but still the group isn't joined.

Comment: I can't say you without debugging this